# How to implement bullet physics in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, bullet-physics

I am new at game development want to know that how can I implement bullet physics in libgdx. I searched lot of things on Internet but nothing found worthy.

Comment: This question is a bit overbroad for our format.

Comment: After studying the links given by Mr. Cameron Fredman I understand the basics of bullet physics but still in dilemma that how can i implement bullet physics in 2d game built in libgdx platform. I need some kind of sample code or tutorial which help me.

Comment: @NishantAnindya I know I'm like 2 years late, but for documentating purposes: for 2D games, use Box2D, it's a lot simpler and enough for 2D physics. Let Bullet only for your 3D games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, this question is a bit overbroad, but [here's the source code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39448/gdx/bullet_gdx_src.zip) for the JNI bullet engine in libgdx.  And [here's the wiki](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Main_Page).  The Bullet User Manual is a pdf file located in the root of the Bullet Physics SDK, which might make a good place to start.

You'll need to add gdx-bullet.jar and gdx-bullet-natives.jar to your desktop project, and gdx-bullet.jar to your Android project. You’ll also need to copy the libgdx-bullet.so files from the extensions/gdx-bullet/armeabi and armeabi-v7a folders to your Android project’s libs/armeabi and armeabi-v7a folders of course.

And there's this from [the google codebase](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/PhysicsBullet):

> Setting up Bullet with libgdx To use bullet physics in your project,
>   you’ll need to add gdx-bullet.jar to your main project. Alternatively
>   you can add the gdx-bullet project to the projects of the build path
>   of your main project.
>
> For your desktop project you’ll need to add the gdx-bullet-natives.jar
>   to the libraries.
>
> For your android project you’ll need to copy the
>   armeabi/libgdx-bullet.so and armeabi-v7a/libgdx-bullet.so files to the
>   libs folder in your android project.
>
> Bullet isn’t supported for GWT at the moment.
>
> Initializing Bullet Before you can use Bullet, you’ll need to load the
>   libraries. This can be done by adding the following line in your
>   create method:
>
> `Bullet.init();`

There's a good deal more information at the links provided above.

Comment: I'd add for anyone that finds this that Xoppa has some [great tutroials](http://blog.xoppa.com/).